# How to handle parsing errors in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `scrapy` to crawl some websites.

In my `parse` method, which is the default parsing method, what can I do when the response is not what I expected, for example, the response is None.

In the `scrapy` doc,

> This method, as well as any other Request callback, must return an iterable of Request and/or Item objects.

But when you have errors, first you can't return a item and second, in my situation, no more requests are returned.

I can't just `return` either, because the `parse` method is an `iterator` that contains `yield`.

I can think of one possible solution: just `yield` an illegal item and drop it in the pipeline.

Any better ideas?

Comment: I try to `yield` an illegal item when, say, the response is None. But this solution is not perfect, after the program have `yield` an illegal item, the code proceeds and crashes due to the fact the `response.body` is empty.

Comment: Does it kill your crawl? callbacks can fail, scrapy is usually fine with it

Comment: @paultrmbrth Yes, it kills the crawl, and `Scrapy` will automatically restart with the following requests. But this is obviously not a very graceful solution.

Comment: You should post your code and traceback

Comment: @paultrmbrth In fact, all I want is something like a early `return`: when I know  that the `response.body` is None, I would like to log the error and `return` to    skip the following parsing process. But I can't use `return` since the parse method contains `yield`

Comment: what about: def parse(...): if response.body is not None: ...do something ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69863/discussion-between-shuai-zhang-and-paul-trmbrth).